# Как проверить включаемый заголовок из пользовательской папки

Tags: cmake

Как можно проверить существование включаемого заголовка, если он генерируется `CMake` при помощи:

```
configure_file(include/config.h.in config.h)
```

Т.е. если я напишу в `CMakeLists.txt` примерно так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

...

...

...

include(CheckIncludeFile)

configure_file(include/config.h.in config.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ...)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

check_include_file(config.h HAVE_CONFIG_H)
```

То, в выводе я увижу что он не может найти включаемый файл:

```
-- Looking for config.h
-- Looking for config.h - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Как можно проверить на существование файла конфигурации из пользовательской папки включения?

Comment: просто интересно: а зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Необходимо для определения есть ли пользовательский конфигупационный файл или нет

Comment: может для таких случаев лучше использовать `add_custom_target` с `copy_if_different`?

Comment: а нет, это ведь скопирует даже если файл пользователя существует